# handling 2 lists in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am rephrasing my earlier question as the output requirement is changed.

two lists

```
fruit_type={apple, apple, orange, orange, pineapple, pineapple, pineapple}
num_type = {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2}
```

Output Expected

```
apple 2
apple 1
orange 1 2
pineapple 3
pineapple 1 2
```

Comment: And the logic behind the output expected is?.. And please call'em lists when you ask about TCL

Comment: read fruit_type until the num_type are in ascending order and then lappend them together for that fruit_type. If num_type are not in ascending order, then break the loop and lappend the fruit_type with associated num_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc debugityourself-or-maybe-even-port-to-tcl8.4 {fruit_type num_type} {
    foreach fruit $fruit_type num $num_type {
        if {[info exists result]&&
            ([lindex $result end-1 0] eq $fruit)&&
            ([lindex $result end end] <= $num)} {
            lset result end [list {*}[lindex $result end] $num] 
        } else {
            lappend result [list $fruit] [list $num]
        }
    }
    if {[info exists result]} {
        return [concat {*}$result]
    }
}
```

UPD: as requirements has changed again, here is a new version:

```
proc fruits-of-labour-for-new-requirements {fruit_type num_type} {
    foreach fruit $fruit_type num $num_type {
        if {[info exists resultF]&&
            ([lindex $resultF end] eq $fruit)&&
            ([lindex $resultN end end] <= $num)} {
            lset resultN end [list {*}[lindex $resultN end] $num]
        } else {
            lappend resultF $fruit
            lappend resultN [list $num]
        }
    }
    if {[info exists resultF]} {
        # $resultF is a list of fruits, $resultN is a list of
        # lists with corresponding numbers.
        return [list $resultF $resultN]
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting some compilation issues.Can you please explain your code

Comment: Compilation issues -- are you trying to compile TCL? Where did you get the compiler? And yeah, I can explain my code. It does what you said, like, looping and comparing the last processed fruit/num (if any) with the current one, either modifying the last pair of elements or creating a new pair. Those pairs are kept in a list of lists. And in the end, all lists in that list of lists are concatenated to get the output you specified.

Comment: Thanks alot.How can We lappend the fruit_type and num_type to different variable instead of putting it into result

Comment: Easily, we just lappend them to different variables and use those variables for comparison (eq $fruit.. <= $num). But you change the requirements again - good luck with next question.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Although, I have accepted your answer. Thanks for your time. Can you please also tell me how can I lappend fruit_type and num_type to a different variable. Thanks again

Comment: Edited the answer, including a new variant with fruit_type and num_type appended to different variables. The new procedure returns a list of two elements: (1) a list of fruits, (2) a list of corresponding lists of numbers for the fruits.

Comment: Hi Anton, need your help to know if we can make decision if the list is in order or not. If the list is not in order for example as stated in my original question, then we can set the flag to false otherwise true. For example 2      scenarios                                                              Out_of_order_list      In_order_List
ID    Type    ID Type
2 Apple    1  Apple
1 Apple    2 Apple
3 Pineapple   1 Pineapple
1 Pineapple   2 Pineapple
2   Pineapple   3 Pineapple